# when i include boost header i have an error: Info: Nothing to build for myTest

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, boost, compiler-errors

I install boost library and i want to test it. I build and run the following project. But i have a problem. When i include <boost/asio.hpp>, CDT build console prints this "Info: Nothing to build for MyTestProject" and it doesn't print anything to  MyTestProject.exe console. If i comment out <boost/asio.hpp>, it prints "Hello world!". What is the problem? I'm using mingw-64, eclipse CDT, boost_1_68_0 on windows. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
//#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  //boost::asio::io_context io;
  //boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  //t.wait();

  cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have Eclipse installed currently. Is there some project settings window where you can see the full command line used to invoke gcc? Is "nothing to build..." the only message displayed?

Comment: `Nothing to build` as in you have already built the obj and exe files? You have not provided enough detail to debug the issue.

Comment: When i build project:
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++0x "-IC:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_68" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\MyTestProject.o" "..\\src\\MyTestProject.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\boost\\lib\\" -o MyTestProject.exe "src\\MyTestProject.o" -lws2_32 -llibboost_iostreams-mgw63-mt-x32-1_68 -llibboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-x32-1_68 -llibboost_system-mgw63-mt-x32-1_68 

Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings.
After i click run project:
 "Info: Nothing to build for MyTestProject" and it doesn't print anything to MyTestProject.exe console. @JohnFilleau

Comment: What happens when you run this compiled MyTestProject.exe from the command line? Are you sure you're editing `src\MyTestProject.cpp` (and not `build\MyTetsProject.cpp`)? If you can expand your file explorer on the left side of the screen and post a screenshot of that it might help.

Comment: i find the solution. I add libboost_system-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_68.dll file to my project directory(..\Users\workspace\MyTestProject). Actually, i have already added -L c:\boost\lib and -l libboost_system-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_68 into linker. Also boost is added to PATH. I don't know why it cannot find the dll, but for now i solved problem in this way. @JohnFilleau